# Dynamics CRM 2011 html web resource content update

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a custom form contains a HTML web resource and there is a combo box in HTML web resource.

When I change selected item in the combo box and click save button on the top of page, page does not detect the combo box change and as a result there is no Save.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: @Rahul Purush, you're really fix fatal typographical errors. Thank you

Comment: Er, thanks! Not sure if that was meant as a sarcastic comment (sorry if I misread it), but it is just my 2 cents to making SO a better place.

Comment: Offcourse it's sarcastic, you did almost nothing there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field in the form (hidden but *not* read only), then make the web resource change it and the CRM will pick up on it.

You could also explicitely invoke `Xrm.Page.data.entity.save()` if you want to initiate a save when user acts inside the web resource.